# Using namespaces in Oracle XMLTable query returns no results (works without them)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, xmltable

Querying a very large set of XML data in Oracle 11g (datafeeds, 65k rows), and I need to match against existing users in a table with ~240k records.  We store the XML data in a binary XML column and use an xmltable() query, and we've registered a schema that is valid and that the XML data we're sending validates against (from within Oracle).

For testing purposes, I'm using a dozen records and executing just the subset query:

```sql
select dfids.*
from   gsu.datafeed_xmldata gdfxml,
          xmltable('/UserIdentifications/OrgIds/OrgId'
                   passing gdfxml.xml_data_binary
                   columns LEGAL_ORG_ID varchar2(32) path 'LegalOrg',
                           LOCAL_ID     varchar2(32) path 'LocalId') dfids
```

This query returns the dozen records quickly, with no problem.  The 65k records take about 16 minutes.  So we wrote this:

```sql
select dfids.*
from   gsu.datafeed_xmldata gdfxml,
      xmltable(xmlnamespaces('http://xmlns.te.com/infosec/useridentifications_binary3.xsd' as "ids"), 
               '/ids:UserIdentifications/ids:OrgIds/ids:OrgId'
               passing gdfxml.xml_data_binary
               columns LEGAL_ORG_ID varchar2(32) path 'ids:LegalOrg',
                       LOCAL_ID     varchar2(32) path 'ids:LocalId') dfids
```

We now get 0 records.  All variations of the paths and columns, with prefixes and without, with different prefixes, using the schema URL, using the qualified schema URL, re-registering the schema, recreating the table... nothing works.  It's been three days of digging through a landfill of slightly related answers and solutions, none of which helped.  I feel like this should be a simple answer - what am I doing wrong?

### Technical Details

Table that holds the xml data:

```
create table xxx.DATAFEED_XMLDATA
(
  xml_data_binary SYS.XMLTYPE 
)
xmltype xml_data_binary store as binary xml
tablespace xxx_DATA_A
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 32M
    next 4M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

A minimal set of xml records (there are three ways of uniquely identifying a user – don't ask, it's a sore subject):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserIdentifications>
  <UserIds>
    <UserId>
      <Id>ABC12345</Id>
    </UserId>
    <UserId>
      <Id>DEF67890</Id>
    </UserId>
  </UserIds>
  <PerNrs>
    <PerNr>
      <Id>00987654</Id>
    </PerNr>
    <PerNr>
      <Id>00341256</Id>
    </PerNr>
  </PerNrs>
  <OrgIds>
    <OrgId>
      <LegalOrg>0420</LegalOrg>
      <LocalId>11432</LocalId>
    </OrgId>
    <OrgId>
      <LegalOrg>0619</LegalOrg>
      <LocalId>334266</LocalId>
    </OrgId>
  </OrgIds>
</UserIdentifications>
```

Schema details:

```
select * 
from   sys.user_xml_schemas;

http://xmlns.te.com/infosec/useridentifications_binary3.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/schemas/xxx/xmlns.te.com/infosec/useridentifications_binary3.xsd (qualified)
local = yes
hier_type = contents
binary = yes
```

The schema itself (as registered, pulled from the above query):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:oraxdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb"
id="UserIdentificationsSchema" oraxdb:flags="2122017"
oraxdb:schemaURL="http://xmlns.te.com/infosec/useridentifications_binary3.xsd"
oraxdb:schemaOwner="GSU_SOURCE" oraxdb:numProps="11"
xmlns:csx="http://xmlns.oracle.com/2004/CSX">
  <xs:element name="UserIdentifications"
  xmlns:csx="http://xmlns.oracle.com/2004/CSX"
  csx:propertyID="2831" oraxdb:global="true" oraxdb:memType="258">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
          <csx:kidList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb">
            <csx:kid csx:propertyID="2823" kidNum="1"></csx:kid>
            <csx:kid csx:propertyID="2826" kidNum="2"></csx:kid>
            <csx:kid csx:propertyID="2830" kidNum="3"></csx:kid>
          </csx:kidList>
        </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:all minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="UserIds" csx:propertyID="2823"
        oraxdb:global="false" oraxdb:memType="258"
        oraxdb:MemInline="false" oraxdb:SQLInline="true"
        oraxdb:JavaInline="false">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <csx:kidList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb">
                  <csx:kid csx:propertyID="2822" kidNum="1">
                  </csx:kid>
                </csx:kidList>
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element name="UserId" csx:propertyID="2822"
              oraxdb:global="false" oraxdb:memType="258"
              oraxdb:MemInline="false" oraxdb:SQLInline="true"
              oraxdb:JavaInline="false">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <csx:kidList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                      xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb">
                        <csx:kid csx:propertyID="2821" kidNum="1">
                        </csx:kid>
                      </csx:kidList>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                  <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="Id" csx:propertyID="2821"
                    oraxdb:global="false" csx:encodingType="string"
                    oraxdb:memType="1" oraxdb:MemInline="true"
                    oraxdb:SQLInline="true"
                    oraxdb:JavaInline="true">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse">
                          </xs:whiteSpace>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="PerNrs" csx:propertyID="2826"
        oraxdb:global="false" oraxdb:memType="258"
        oraxdb:MemInline="false" oraxdb:SQLInline="true"
        oraxdb:JavaInline="false">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <csx:kidList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb">
                  <csx:kid csx:propertyID="2825" kidNum="1">
                  </csx:kid>
                </csx:kidList>
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element name="PerNr" csx:propertyID="2825"
              oraxdb:global="false" oraxdb:memType="258"
              oraxdb:MemInline="false" oraxdb:SQLInline="true"
              oraxdb:JavaInline="false">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <csx:kidList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                      xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb">
                        <csx:kid csx:propertyID="2824" kidNum="1">
                        </csx:kid>
                      </csx:kidList>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                  <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="Id" csx:propertyID="2824"
                    oraxdb:global="false" csx:encodingType="string"
                    oraxdb:memType="1" oraxdb:MemInline="true"
                    oraxdb:SQLInline="true"
                    oraxdb:JavaInline="true">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse">
                          </xs:whiteSpace>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="OrgIds" csx:propertyID="2830"
        oraxdb:global="false" oraxdb:memType="258"
        oraxdb:MemInline="false" oraxdb:SQLInline="true"
        oraxdb:JavaInline="false">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <csx:kidList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb">
                  <csx:kid csx:propertyID="2829" kidNum="1">
                  </csx:kid>
                </csx:kidList>
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element name="OrgId" csx:propertyID="2829"
              oraxdb:global="false" oraxdb:memType="258"
              oraxdb:MemInline="false" oraxdb:SQLInline="true"
              oraxdb:JavaInline="false">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <csx:kidList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                      xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb">
                        <csx:kid csx:propertyID="2827" kidNum="1">
                        </csx:kid>
                        <csx:kid csx:propertyID="2828" kidNum="2">
                        </csx:kid>
                      </csx:kidList>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                  <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="LegalOrg"
                    csx:propertyID="2827" oraxdb:global="false"
                    csx:encodingType="string" oraxdb:memType="1"
                    oraxdb:MemInline="true" oraxdb:SQLInline="true"
                    oraxdb:JavaInline="true">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse">
                          </xs:whiteSpace>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="LocalId"
                    csx:propertyID="2828" oraxdb:global="false"
                    csx:encodingType="string" oraxdb:memType="1"
                    oraxdb:MemInline="true" oraxdb:SQLInline="true"
                    oraxdb:JavaInline="true">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse">
                          </xs:whiteSpace>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: But your xml sample record has no elements with a namespace prefix in it.

Comment: That makes sense... none of the examples out there use namespace prefixes, but it makes sense.  Wouldn't the XML document fail validation against the schema without the prefixes are an issue?